# Getting HibernateProxy.RV3cG0FE after bean name during XML response with spring

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am trying to generate an XML response with Spring boot. In the response XML instead of getting Customer as the root node and I am getting <Customer.HibernateProxy.RV3cG0FE> whereas JSON this is working perfectly fine.

**CustomerBean**
package com.aopexception.model;

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor()
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer
{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", unique = true)
    private Long customerId;
    
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 20)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = 20)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", length = 50)
    private String address;
    
}
```

**Controller**
package com.aopexception.controllers;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.aopexception.MyAopException;
import com.aopexception.model.Customer;
import com.aopexception.service.CustomerService;

@RestController
public class CustomerController 
{
    @Autowired(required = true)
    CustomerService customerService;
    
    @RequestMapping(
            path = "customer/fetch",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,  
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
    )
    public Customer getCustomer(@RequestParam Long id) throws MyAopException 
    {
        System.out.println("get Customer method invoked ");
        Customer customer = customerService.getCustomer(id);
        return customer;
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
<Customer.HibernateProxy.RV3cG0FE>
    <customerId>102</customerId>
    <firstName>admin</firstName>
    <lastName>admin</lastName>
    <address>India</address>
</Customer.HibernateProxy.RV3cG0FE>
```

Comment: Jackson is generating the response and not JAXB. So the `@XmlRootElement` isn't taken into consideration and it will write the classname, which at that time is a hibernate proxy. Use `@JacksonXmlRootElement` instead (and pass an actual value). Like `@JacksonXmlRootElement("Customer">)`. Another thing is to add the Jackson Hibernate module, which might help as well (although not sure if that helps with the XML part).

Comment: @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Customer") is working. Thanks Deinum.